# SSMS SQL Run as a different User from Excel VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, authentication, runas

I can manually right click on SSMS and choose "Run as a different user" then input my windows authentication user and password which will successfully open the connection to my desired server and DBs.

Is there a way to invoke the "Run as a different User" option from Excel VBA and pass through the User and Password details?

[image: Run as different user]

The VBA code I currently have is as follows:

```
Public Sub SQL_Data()

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim SystemSever, Systemdb As String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim CMD As ADODB.Command
Dim SQL_1 As String

SystemServer = "ServerName"
Systemdb = "DBName"

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Conn.CommandTimeout = 60000
Conn.ConnectionTimeout = 60000
Conn.Open "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=" & SystemServer & ";DATABASE=" & Systemdb & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;OPTION=16427"

Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset
Set CMD = New ADODB.Command

With CMD
    .ActiveConnection = Conn
End With

With RS
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
End With

SQL_1 = "SELECT ....... " & _
        "FROM .......... "
RS.Open SQL_1, Conn, adOpenStatic

If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("Table_Data")) > 1 Then Range("Table_Data").Delete
Range("Table_Data").CopyFromRecordset RS

RS.Close
Set CMD = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: A potentially superior option is to use the Credential Manager to store the credentials for `server:1433`. This way, no applications have to bother with `runas` in any form at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert please could you expand on that a bit more?  How would I write this into the VBA Code?

Comment: You don't -- Credential Manager is a built-in Windows component (accessed from Start) that can store alternate credentials for domain authentication per server. If you stored a credential for a server in there (with port 1433), then, on connecting to SQL Server, the authentication bits in Windows would automatically use that credential. This is transparent to applications. The only time this doesn't work/is insufficient is when you need to connect to the same server with different credentials depending on the scenario, or if administrators have locked down the use of Credential Manager.

Comment: @JeroenMostert please see my "answer" below.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I can't get the Credential Manager to work.  It won't seem to accept a server name which has a \ in it.  How can I get round this?  For example, my servername would be: AB-CDEF-1\GHIJ

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have read in other posts that I need the fqdn.  How do I find out what this is? SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'MachineName'); works and gives me the AB-CDEF-1 part of my server.  What else am I missing from the fqdn?

Comment: If the server name is `AB-CDEF-1`, then `AB-CDEF-1\GHIJ` would be the instance `GHIJ` on server `AB-CDEF-1`. To work with those in stored credentials, you need to know the port the instance is actually listening on. Try querying `sys.dm_exec_connections` and look at the `local_tcp_port` column. The default instance uses port 1433, but named instances will use something else. If the server is reachable from your machine, the FQDN should be produced if you do `ping AB-CDEF-1` from the command line (I don't think using the FQDN is strictly necessary, but the port definitely is).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Unfortunately I don't have permission to see `sys.dm_exec_connections`  I also don't have access to the server directly so I can't go in and ping the server from command prompt.  Please continue to help me, I feel like I'm so close to getting this done.

Comment: Connect to the server like you normally would with SSMS, then do `netstat -f` from the command prompt. Under "foreign address", you'll see the server host name, and the port your machine is connecting to. That'll be the instance port.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I use a Remote Desktop. I then run SSMS as a different User. I then open Command Prompt. When I type in 'netstat -f' the 'AB-CDEF-1' server name doesn't show in the list of results.  When I try to find what's using port 1433 (should be SSMS) by typing in 'netstat -aon | findstr :1433' I get two rows returned, one saying TCP 0.0.0.0:1433 and the other saying TCP [::]:1433   I have also tried 'ping AB-CDEF-1' and it then says 'pinging AB-CDEF-1.live.company.local [10.100.0.200]'  Does this mean anything?